# ReactJS map: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression - no-unused-expressions

Tags: reactjs, variable-assignment, map-function

I'm in the midst of cleaning up errors for a repo and I've come across this error where someone's trying to to assign a tag value object to a const variable inside of a map function. Here's its current form:

```
const BatchEditState = {
    CURRENT: 'CURRENT',
    DELETE: 'DELETE',
    PUT: 'PUT',
}
```

```
handleShow = () => {
        this.batchEditSet = {};
        this.state.currentTags.map((tag) => {
            this.batchEditSet[tag.tag_name] = BatchEditState.CURRENT;
        });
    };
```

As far as I've researched, one is definitely not supposed to go about it this way even if it does still function. I've seen plenty examples returning a jsx element, but I'm pretty sure that's not the point for this. I do know a map function is supposed to at least return a value however.

I attempted to use a spread operator and an implicit return, but that didn't work out. I also tried making a basic return & even though I'm not encountering any immediate errors in our application, I'm still not sure if this is the right way to go. Still fairly new at this, but appreciate any info, help, and education I can get

```
handleShow = () => {
        this.batchEditSet = {};
        this.state.currentTags.map((tag) => {
            this.batchEditSet[tag.tag_name] = BatchEditState.CURRENT;
            return(
                BatchEditState.CURRENT
            )
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.map` is only for creating new arrays by iterating over an existing array. While you want to iterate over an existing array, you don't want to create a new array - rather, you want to construct a plain object - so `.map` should not be used here. (The array you're constructing in your current code is going unused.)

To procedurally assign to properties of the object, do:

```
handleShow = () => {
  this.batchEditSet = {};
  this.state.currentTags.forEach((tag) => {
    this.batchEditSet[tag.tag_name] = BatchEditState.CURRENT;
  });
};
```

Or create an array of entries, then turn that array into an object.

```
handleShow = () => {
  this.batchEditSet = Object.fromEntries(
    this.state.currentTags.map(tag => [tag.tag_name, BatchEditState.CURRENT])
  );
};
```

But also, doing `this.batchEditSet =` in the first place looks like a mistake in React. If this is a component, you should almost certainly be calling `this.setState` instead of mutating the instance.

Comment: Thank you! I believe the previous dev that came up with this did intend to assign to properties of the object. This is for sure a step in the right direction. A lot of code here was copy/pasted and from an older version of react too. So there's going to be a lot of cleanup involved past this. Definitely appreciate the explanation & quick help!